# Is the URL Format Correct After Sending the Parameters with Get Method ? (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, get

I'm doing a database query with GET method. So the form as follows;

```
<form action="" method="get>
  <input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="white" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="red" />
</form>
```

After the form is submitted, incoming form values are querying in controller as follows;

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
  $socks = Sock::whereNotNull('created_at');

  if ($request->has('color')) {
        $socks ->whereIn('color', $request->input('color'));
    }

  $socks = $socks->paginate(20);

  return;
 }
```

After the function return, URL format as follows;

```
search?color%5B%5D=white&color%5B%5D=red
```

Is this URL format correct ? Need the change query method ?

Comment: Possibly unrelated: `methot` should be `method`

Comment: Do you always have two search parameters is it different every time?

Comment: Not always two, depending on what i want. They will probably be dynamic. But first i need to learn if this URL format is correct for SEO.

Comment: So you shuld do a POST request, not a get, otherwise it will never be good for SEO... or if you prefer to make a script that submits to /search/color/red-white-blue, and explode the values in your controller you can have a SEO friendly URL

Comment: Thank you for answer but i've never seen filtering with the POST method.